# Unable to access loaded & total object in progressEvent of axios request

Tags: react-native, file-upload, axios

I'm working on a react native project where I need to make a progress bar for uploading a file.
here is my code, kindly check it out.

`axios.post(urlRequest, requestData, {
        headers: headerConfig,
        onUploadProgress: function (progressEvent) {
          console.log('progressEvent : ', progressEvent);
          console.dir('progressEvent loaded : ', progressEvent.loaded);
          console.dir('progressEvent total : ', progressEvent.total);
        },`

in the response of this function, I'm getting following console output.
[image: output console screenshot]

As you can see here, I'm getting loaded & total object inside `Symbol(original_event)` but, I can't access them.
Any Idea? how can I use them?

Answer (score 1):

1. i think `console.dir` accepts and returns only object not string 'progressEvent '.
2. And Path to object you are pointing is wrong `progressEvent.Symbol.loaded`.

Comment: thanks for you answer. @Ram, but none of both are work for me.